# Add additional services to product cart

Tags: cart, shopping-cart-price-rules, addtocart, additional-information

Is it possible to add a addional option inside the cart, just as the screenshot?
The additional option is different for each category.

I already use the up and cross sell options, so I can not use them.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? And what is your exact problem? Or do you want an outline how to do this?

Comment: @FabianBlechschmidt Thanks for your reply. I am looking for a solution to achieve this, so that I can apply additional services to products to purchase. So I want to know what is the best way to achieve this? Are there some extentions that I can use for this? etc.

Comment: Did you try product custom options ? Try pairing them up with some extension that allows to change them in cart page.

Comment: @Prateek Thanks. What extension do you mean to achieve this?

Comment: I can't recommend since I haven't used any. Try with basic google search and see what results you get.